# AEM-6.4 Original Value of sling:resourceSuperType for /libs/foundation/components/redirect

Tags: aem, sling

I have accidentally make changes to the sling:resourceSuperType value of /libs/foundation/components/redirect in CRXDE. I have tried to google from AEM site like https://www.aemcomponents.dev/ to get the answer, but still no avail.

I would like to know the original value that set to the sling:resourceSuperType. It will be good if someone can share the value here, or will even better if able to share any other site and guide that can get the original properties of each AEM components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**foundation/components/page**  is the ***sling:resourceSupertype*** for **/libs/foundation/components/redirect**

(The 'redirect' component refers to a page. Hence, its super-type is 'page')

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also you can always copy your jar with a new name and port and extract it. It will create a vanilla system and there you can check it.